# MySQL hierarchical parent child id

Tags: mysql, tree

help me
i'm have probelme with hirerarchi graph. i have table mysql like this :

```html
+------+------+-------+
+ from +  to  + value +
+------+------+-------+
+   1  +   2  +    2  +
+   1  +   3  +    3  +
+   1  +   4  +    4  +
+   2  +   5  +    5  +
+   2  +   6  +    4  +
+   3  +   5  +    3  +
+   4  +   7  +    2  +
+   5  +   7  +    1  +
+   6  +   7  +    2  +
+------+------+-------+
```

and i'm want to show query like this :

```html
+-------+----------+------------+
+ node1 + 1,2,6,7  + sum(value) +
+-------+----------+------------+
+ node2 + 1,2,5,7  + sum(value) +
+-------+----------+------------+
+ node3 + 1,3,5,7  + sum(value) +
+-------+----------+------------+
+ node4 + 1,4,7    + sum(value) +
+-------+----------+------------+
```

i hope anyone can help me with query mysql or mysql procedure. please :(

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: please give me your logic

Comment: That's not how things work around here - StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).